# Как обновить содержимое фрагмента в viewpager?

Tags: java, android

У меня 2 фрагмента в viewpager. Во фрагментах recycleview. Также есть service, который должен обновлять эти списки. Подскажите как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

RecyclerView обновляется когда обновляется его adapter. Чтобы adapter узнал что обновлены данные ему надо указать с помощью метода notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: Это понятно. Как мне достучаться до нужного фрагмента, который в pageview, чтобы обновить rexycleview?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант попробовать через BroadcastReceiver

В сервисе:

```
public static final String SERVICE_REQUEST = "com.example.app.service.SERVICE_REQUEST";
// ...
Intent data = new Intent(SERVICE_REQUEST);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ServiceClass.this).sendBroadcast(data);
```

Во фрагменте:

```
// при создании фрагмента
reseiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // тут можно обновить адаптер
            }
}
// ...
@Override
public void onStop() {
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(reseiver);
       super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(reseiver, new IntentFilter(ServiceClass.SERVICE_REQUEST));
}
```